# Iterating over stdout

Tags: ansible

I am writing a playbook to locate a string pattern in a sequence of files. If I run my utility through the command module it will generate one or more strings on STDOUT. To run this across a number of systems I would like to run the command with_items:

```
  - command: "findstring {{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "string1"
    - "string2"
  register: found
  failed_when: found.rc >= 2
```

And then iterate over the result to post process the info:

```
 - name: Print strings we found   
   debug:
     var: "{{ item }}"   
   with_items: found.results
```

Is there something equivalent to loop.index that can be used with "results" in the task above? This would allow me to do something like  {{ item[INDEX].stdout }} to get the strings that were generated. I haven't been able to find an answer in the official documentation so I thought I would post here to see what the gurus think.

Comment: You've got at least three distinct problems in the code you posted; ranging from using outdated syntax to putting things together without even checking the values of your variables. Try troubleshooting and isolate the real problem.

Comment: The formatting may be off but the code runs correctly with ansible 2.3.1.0.

Comment: In a language (like YAML) in which formatting is significant, you need to ensure that the code you post is correct. Otherwise we can't tell "real problem" from "you forgot to indent something".  It would also help to include in your question the contents of the `found` variable after the first task (e.g., include the output of a `debug` task with `var: found`).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to iterate over every line from all commands, use:

```
- debug:
    msg: "Do smth for line {{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ found | json_query('results[].stdout_lines[]') }}"
```

This will take ever element from `found.results`, then every element from every `stdout_lines`.

Comment: This will require the `jmespath` library to be installed first.

Answer (score 0):

For me this works in `ansible [core 2.11.6]`:

```
- name: Command which outputs multiple lines
  ansible.builtin.command: 
    cmd: ls -l /
  register: _ls_cmd
  changed_when: no

- name: Debug to show each line
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "ITEM: {{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ _ls_cmd.stdout_lines }}"
```